# Equivalent function for Math.signum(double) for int or long in Java

Tags: java, math, primitive

Is there an equivalent function for **Math.signum(double)** or **Math.signum(float)** in Java for other primitive numbers like **int** or **long**. I don't want to write code like

```
  int sign = (int) Math.signum((double) intValue);
```

when there is a better alternative.

Comment: Integer.signum(int i) and Long.signum(long l)

Comment: write your own method? all it takes is `return i > 0 ? 1 : i < 0 ? -1 : 0;`. **or** you could `import static` the `Integer.signum` and `Long.signum` methods

Comment: @AMB you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Docs for Integer.signum: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum-int-

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use it this way:

[Integer.signum(int i)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum-int-) and [Long.signum(long l)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#signum-long-)

Link to javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum-int-

Comment: Added to the answer too, tyvm

Answer (score 2):

Just an addendum of some implementation details of that :

```
public static int signum(int i) {
    // HD, Section 2-7
    return (i >> 31) | (-i >>> 31);
}
```

`Integer::signum` says : I'll give you `-1` if the number is negative, `0` if number is zero and `1` if number is positive. This is fairly trivial via some nested `if/else` for example.

Instead JDK uses a solution that is a bit more fancy. `(x >> 31) | (-x >>> 31)`. Looks easy right? the first part : `x >> 31` is *signed shift to the right*; it's called signed because it keeps the sign after the shift.

Suppose we live in a world where 4 bits numbers exist only (for simplicity).

We have `0100` (+4), a single shift `0100 >> 1` will make it `0010` (+2). Now, if our number is `1100` (-4; the first bit is the sign), a shift *signed* to the right : `1100 >> 1` is `1110` (-2). Do a division, but keep the sign.

Thus if we shift 31 times, we throw away the last 31 bits of the number, move the bit for the sign in the least significant position and keep the original sign. Or in simple words take the 31 bit, put it into 0 position and throw away everything else.

```
 0 00000 ..... 11111
 x --------------->0 // x is kept
        ignore
```

The second part `-x >>> 31` is a *unsigned* shift, meaning the sign is *not* kept when we shift.

For example `0100 >>> 1` (+4) will give you `0010` (+2).  Nothing is really different so far from the *signed* shift and the example above. The interesting part comes when numbers are negative:

`1100` (-4) and we try to shift it once : `1100 >>> 1`, because the sign is *not* kept, we put zero in the most significant bit and move to the right, thus we get : `0110` (+6!).

In reality, taking 32 bits into the picture. `-4 == 1111...111100` and we shift it to the right: sign is zero, everything else is moved to the right, thus: `0111...11110` or `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1`.

```
System.out.println(-4 >>> 1);
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1);
```

Thus the part `x >>> 31` will move the sign bit into the least significant position, zeroing everything else. No matter the number you give it, you will always get `1` or `0`.

```
1 00000 ..... 11111
x --------------->1 // x is "zeroed also"
       ignore
```

And the addition of `-x` to that `x >>> 31` is simply done so that `|` would work correctly satisfy our needed result.

Comment: The guy who created this source, must really like 1's and 0's...  Good one, tnx. +1